# Does `origin` have any special meaning_?

Tags: git

I've setup a few github repos using this documentation:

```
echo "# foo" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/foo-1/foo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Does the name `origin` have any special meaning?

If so is it purely semantical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now just the default name for the cloned upstream repo.
But it used to be a branch as well originally (up until git 1.5.0 in early 2007):

The very first commit introducing '`origin`' dates from [1cadb5a (July 2005, git 0.99.2)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cadb5a2719eef7dc4e707ee2f796c94661f4622).
It is followed by [commit a692b96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a692b9656a7975b933fde40cdd6319f9ca898a29), which explained:

> A recommended work cycle for an "individual developer" who does not have a "public" repository is somewhat different.  It goes like this:
>
> (1) Prepare your work repository, by "`git clone`" the public repository of the "project lead" (or a "subsystem maintainer", if you work on a subsystem).
>   The URL used for the initial cloning is stored in `.git/branches/origin`.
>
> (2) Do your work there.  Make commits.
>
> (3) Run "`git fetch origin`" from the public repository of your upstream every once in a while.  This does only the first half of "git pull" but does not merge.
>   The head of the  public repository is stored in `.git/refs/heads/origin`.

That workflow was obviously very much tailored to the distributed development of the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), in which you had only *one* upstream repo.

---

The `.git/branches/origin` won't become `.git/remotes/origin` before [commit 6687f8f (Aug. 2005, git v0.99.5)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6687f8fea22e1e43ab163a8fe180155a0a0a956a), when you can **fetch more than one upstream repo**.

> Now multi-head fetch is complete, let's migrate the default configuration for new repositories created with the "`git clone`" command.
>
> The original `$GIT_DIR/branches` is not deprecated yet, but create remotes directory by default from the templates as well.

---

Then [commit e125c1a (Nov. 2005, v0.99.9c)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e125c1a717bb732319596d8b792a67c2b7b15ef7) added:

> The newly cloned repository by default had `.git/remotes/origin` set up to track the remote `master` to `origin`, but forgot to create the `origin` branch ourselves.
>   Also it hardcoded the assumption that the remote `HEAD` points at "`master`", which may not always be true.

---

It started to evolve to 'origin' as an upstream repo in [commit dfeff66 (March 2006, git 1.3.0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfeff66ed9a3931d60f3cd600ad8c14b5cc3d9e5), where:

> The upstream branch heads are copied in `.git/refs/remotes/` instead of  `.git/refs/heads/` and `.git/remotes/origin` file is set up to reflect this as well.
>   It requires to have fetch/pull update to understand `.git/refs/remotes` by Eric Wong to further update the repository cloned this way.

This is detailed in [commit c72112e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c72112e6e1593bd77132a815ba484d0ff880a7b4).

---

Defaulting to 'origin' when fetching was introduced in [commit 5e27e27 (July 2006, git 1.4.2)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e27e27e5d3da5dcbe5fbfe204c2ade0128538a5).

---

The remote `origin` is stored in `./git/config` in [commit 255cae8 (Nov. 2006, git 1.5.0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/255cae88bcc8fcb0088459df13b55fa3d311b9e2)

> For example what was previously `.git/remotes/origin`:

```
  URL: proto://host/path
  Pull: refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin
```

> Is now added to `.git/config` as:

```
  [remote "origin"]
  url = proto://host/path
  fetch = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin
```

---

`git pull` defaults to `origin` with [commit 955289b (Dec. 2006, git 1.5.0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/955289bf92f0513377763c9aacfe426d5151b05a):

Without any specification in the `.git/config` file, `git-pull` will execute
"`git-pull origin`"; which in turn defaults to pull from the first "pull"
definition for the remote, "`origin`".

The [glossary is then updated](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f65bb2c66fbebc10810857c64466679c81bf8154):

> **`origin`**:
>
> The default upstream repository. **Most projects have at least one upstream project which they track. By default '`origin`' is used for that purpose**.
>   New upstream updates will be fetched into remote tracking branches named `origin/name-of-upstream-branch`, which you can see using "`git branch -r`".